# Postgresql group by multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Let's say I have this table:

| sellerid | buyerid | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | xyz | 100.00 |
| abc | xyz | 500.00 |
| ikj | abc | 200.00 |
| ikj | abc | 300.00 |

And I need to get the sum of price for each id (sellerid and buyerid):

| id | total |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 11,000.00 |
| xyz | 600.00 |
| ikj | 500.00 |

I'm struggling with the group by part, I can get it to give me the total but then the id is null.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be using `union all` to combine `sellerid` and `buyerid` columns , then using an outer query we can do the aggregation.

With the given data example

```
create table tbl (
  sellerid text ,
  buyerid text ,
  price decimal(5,2) 
);

insert into tbl values  ('abc','xyz',100.00),
('abc','xyz',500.00), ('ikj','abc',200.00),('ikj','abc',300.00);
```

Query

```
select sellerid,sum(price) as tot_Price
from (  
      select sellerid,price from tbl
      union all
      select buyerid,price from tbl
    ) x 
group by sellerid
order by sellerid asc
```

Result

```
sellerid    tot_price
   abc       1100.00
   ikj       500.00
   xyz       600.00
```

---

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQ48qa_Q)